# Not able to print Google map on click of print button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, printing

I am not able to print google map on click of print button using jQuery. I am using version 3 of Google maps API. The map is rendered on the page properly but when I click on print button, it does not print any content of the map. 
Here's the code:

```
printLinks.init = function () {
```

`$('body').on('click', '.js-print-link', function (e) {`

```
var prWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,status,width=600,height=700');
prWin.document.write('<HTML><HEAD><LINK href=/css/print.css ' + ' type="text/css" rel="stylesheet"><title>Print Window</title>');
prWin.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js""></script>');
prWin.document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false&callback=initializeMaps"></script>');
var prCon = document.getElementById('body').innerHTML;
var str1 = $.parseHTML(prCon);
$('<div/>').append(htmlstring).find('#abc').append('<a id="prClick" href="#" class="share-print" onClick="window.print()" style="float:right"></a>');
var str2 = $('<div/>').append(str1);
prWin.document.write(str2.html());
prWin.document.close();
prWin.focus();
e.preventDefault();
});
};
```

To explain above code more, on click of a button present on bottom of the page a new window named "Print Window" opens up of size 600*700 containing the content of original window but with different css named print.css which is being referred here. Original window contains google map as well. On new "Print Window" also, the map appears correctly but when I click on print icon present in the top right corner of "Print Window", the map is not printed at all. Please suggest.

Comment: Can we see the code, how you are trying to print?

Comment: Hi Michel, i have updated the question along with code and some description below it. Please suggest what am I missing here.

Comment: Ok, check my answer below. I think that can help print the map.

Answer (score 0):

```
var printMaps = function () {
        var body               = $('body'),
            mapContainer       = $('#YourMapContainer'),
            mapContainerParent = mapContainer.parent(),

            printContainer     = $('<div>');

        body.prepend(printContainer);
        printContainer
            .addClass('print-container')
            .css('position', 'relative')
            .height(mapContainer.height())
            .append(mapContainer);

        var content = body.children()
            .not('script')
            .not(printContainer)
            .detach();

        window.print();

        body.prepend(content);
        mapContainerParent.prepend(mapContainer);
        printContainer.remove();
    };

    $('#PrintButton').on('click', printMaps);
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate what should i add in css class 'print-container'? and how can i integrate your code with mine? Also, don't i need to include any google map api here?

Comment: `print-container` is basically `width` and `height`. Google map API? Of course and I taught you are using one already.

Comment: This is not working, it still gives content but map is not displayed. Do I need to render dynamic google map first as an image and then print it?

Comment: Here is a Fiddle link with map and a print button: http://jsfiddle.net/glenn/6mx21ted/ This might differ from your map API as this one is Direction API of the map, but can just give you an idea

Comment: No action is performed on click of Print button, can you please check again?